# Multivariable limit - how to solve

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm homelearning multivariable calculus and I am currently trying to solve the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0, y\rightarrow 0}(x+y) \sin\frac{1}{x} \sin\frac{1}{y}$$

How should I solve it? I tried setting $(x,y)$ to $(0,0),$ but it's undefined and I don't know what else to try.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u$ and $v$ be any expressions having a value, then 
$$  -1 \leq \sin(u) \leq 1  $$
and 
$$  -1 \leq \sin(v) \leq 1  $$
so 
$$  -1 \leq \sin(u) \sin(v) \leq 1  \text{.}  $$
Consequently, 
$$  -1(x+y) \leq (x+y)\sin(1/x)\sin(1/y) \leq (x+y)  \text{.}  $$
Now apply the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of the limit, we can use the following lemma. (I am denoting $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ as $x$ and $\sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2}$ as $|x|$.)

*Lemma:* Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $g$ is bounded near $0$ and that $f(x)\to0$ as $x\to0$. Then $f\cdot g(x)\to0$ as $x\to0$.

*Proof:* Suppose $|g|\leq M$ for some fixed constant $M\geq0$. Fix $\varepsilon>0$, and choose $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)|<\varepsilon/M$. Then whenever $|x|<\delta$:
$$|f\cdot g(x)|\leq |f(x)|\cdot M<\frac{\varepsilon}{M}\cdot M=\varepsilon,$$
and so $f\cdot g\to0$ as $x\to0$. $\square$

Now since sine is bounded and $x+y\to0$ as $(x,y)\to0$, the limit in your question is zero.